# JavaScript on IE and Chrome? (It works on Firefox)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function ord(string) {
    var str = string + '',
        code = str.charCodeAt(0);
    if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) { // High surrogate (could change last hex to 0xDB7F to treat high private surrogates as single characters)
        var hi = code;
        if (str.length === 1) {
            return code; // This is just a high surrogate with no following low surrogate, so we return its value;
            // we could also throw an error as it is not a complete character, but someone may want to know }
            var low = str.charCodeAt(1);
            return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
        }
        if (0xDC00 <= code && code <= 0xDFFF) { // Low surrogate return code; // This is just a low surrogate with no preceding high surrogate, so we return its value;
            // we could also throw an error as it is not a complete character, but someone may want to know
        }
        return code;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxTxtNumber = 8;
    var arrTxtNumber = new Array();
    var txtvalues = new Array();
    var arr = {};

    $('.numericonly').keypress(function (e) {
        var t = $(this).val();
        var k = e.which;
        delete arr[8];
        if ((e.which >= 49 && e.which <= 55) || e.which == 8) {
            if (e.which == 8) {
                var s = new String(t);
                s = s.charCodeAt(0);
                delete arr[s];
            }
            if (arr[k]) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                arr[k] = e.which;
            }
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

The code works on Firefox but not on IE and Chrome?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "not working": not working at all or not working as expected (then you have to explain what).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ABCPY/ in indented format. a) What's the intended purpose of this script and b) are you aware that your entire ord function is only ever returning str.charCodeAt(0) or null?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `ord()`.  Why is that code relevant?

Comment: What is the intended behavior?  What is "not working" on IE and Chrome.  "Not Working" is NOT an acceptable description of the problem on StackOverflow.  Tell us exactly what is is doing and what you expected it to do.  Are you getting errors in the console?  How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: What it does is it prevents the user from typing an input from 8 and above and limits the user from typing letters and other special characters.

Comment: the codes are working(it does what it's suppose to) in firefox but does not in IE and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Other browsers use `e.keyCode` to tell you which key was pressed. Cross-browser:

```
var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

Also make sure you use `k` rather than repeating `e.which` every time.

Comment: I was under the impression that jQuery normalizes it to `which` on `keypress`. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/): "While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code."

Answer (score 0):

All that code is not required. If you want to test that an input's value is only digits, then something like the following will do:

```
<input type="text" onblur="check(this);" ...>


function check(el) {
  if (!isDigits(el.value)) {
    alert('Hey!!\nThe element you just left should only contain digits');
  }
}

function isDigits(s) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(s);
}
```

It's much more friendly to give the user a hint about the format you require and wait until they either leave the control or submit the form before offering a warning about invalid values. You really don't care how the user gets to a valid value, just so long as it's valid when the form is submitted.

And you must validate on the server again.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend running your code through a validator such as http://www.jslint.com/ to make sure that everything adheres to universal standards.

Comment: What "universal standard" are you referring to? ECMA-262? W3C DOM? ISO8601? JSLint is for ECMAScript, it will not fix anything to do with host objects or their methods and properties.